# javascript: text messages on global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, text, global

I was reading through my javascript file, and two questions came to my mind:

1) i have 26 strings of text that i use, and some of them gets repeated in several functions.
So i thought if would be a good idea to declare all them as global vars?

2) 95% of my code is javascript, the rest is JQuery. The logics are very simple. Is it worth converting all my JS code to JQuery?

Sample code:

```
    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    document.myForm.submit();
```

Comment: jquery is javascript and declaring globals is not a good idea until it is needed by the design.

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest turning your 5% jQuery code to Plain JavaScript instead. You'll reduce the load of an entire library loading along with your normal code, most of which's functions you don't use nor require.

Comment: Well i use some JQuery functions like .show and .hide on div's. Also i didn't know JavaScript is faster and better than JQuery. I've been told JQuery is a better for cross-browser compatibility, and i have to support FF and IE.

Comment: It isn't only a good idea because JavaScript code by itself is faster, but also because on slower internet connections, your page will load much slower since jQuery will also have to be loaded. This won't be the case for everyone, of course, because of caching.

It is true that jQuery increases cross-browser compatibility, though. But the functions like `.show` can easily be done using CSS, and use JavaScript as a fallback. In the end, it is your decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to group the constant variables in a single spot, so they are defined only once, without duplication, and are easy to look at and modify.

However, I would prefer to group the dictionary into a single object or module. This would reduce clutter on the global namespace, would indicate the variables are connected and would allow you to iterate and manipulate them better (if you wish to do so). It is the same reasoning behind using arrays instead of having x1, x2, ..., xn variables.

```
//setting up the strings
var strings = {
    //string id : string value
    'a' : 'a string',
    'b' : 'another string'
};

//using the strings
console.log( strings.a );
console.log( strings.['a'] );
```

---

Also, jQuery is just a Javascript library. I don't really see a reason to try to convert the code (and risk accidentaly breaking it), given  the info you gave us.

Comment: I'm a beginner in JavaScript, but i'll talk to my boss about this change, to make use of Objects.

Answer (score 2):

1) if you need to access that strings everywhere it could be better to define only one global var in which you store all the strings (it could be an `array` or an `object`) otherwise consider grouping those functions in a closure (a so-called "immediately self executed function") and then declaring that array (or object) inside the scope created. e.g.

```
 (function() {
     var hastrings = {
         'string1' : 'value1',
         'string2' : 'value2',
         ...
     };

     /* all functions using common strings here */

 }());
```

2) It depends: you should take into consideration how many LOC you would write using jQuery-only constructs instead, but remember that some instructions may be more performant using straight javascript (because you would always call the `jQuery` function). So there's not a definitive answer. It could vary depending on what your code does, how much complex it is and how you structured it.

Answer (score 2):

1) According to your scenario you can declare as Global, i you feel global variable is better to write than hard-coding everywhere.

2) Jquery is a javascript framework (ajax)

```
 document.getElementById('email')    is faster than $("#email")
```

so javascript is better to keep, and see if you have any complex code that Jquery is doing with minimal effort, then you can use in those places.